# How to compress text files of N number sub folder which contains N number text files?

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing, rar, winrar

Below is a directory structure where I have to compress all *.txt files in the `app*` subdirectories into a RAR archive with current date in name with deletion of archived files and folders.

I am totally new on working on command line and writing batch scripts and know only some basics.

Are there any suggestions on how to solve this task using *Rar* or *WinRAR*?

```
E: 
Data 
    Log
    makeRar.bat
        app1
            1.txt
            2.txt
            3.txt
            .
            .
            .
            n.txt
        app2
            1.txt
            2.txt
            3.txt
            .
            .
            .
            n.txt
        app3
            1.txt
            2.txt
            3.txt
            .
            .
            .
            n.txt
        .
        .
        .
        appn
            1.txt
            2.txt
            3.txt
            .
            .
            .
            n.txt
```

----------- After execution of makeRar.bat file -------------

```
E: 
Data 
    Log
    makeRar.bat
        app1
            4/1/2016_log.rar
        app2
            4/1/2016_log.rar
        app3
            4/1/2016_log.rar
```

Comment: Apparently even the basics are not within your knowledge base.  You cannot name a file with slashes.

Comment: Are the text files still in existence after you archive them?

Comment: No it should get delete

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have an answer for this problem. But this solution is using a static path, and not a dynamic path. So when this batch file is executed, it produces the output exactly as wanted, but only for a specific `app` folder according to code below.

```
set loc="C:\Program Files\WinRAR"
cd /D %loc%
rar.exe a -r -agYYYY-MM-DD -df -ep %source%\app1\log_.rar %source%\app1\*.txt
```

`source` must be defined with path of source directory.

**EDIT:**

I found a better solution for this task for your directory structure by iterating two **FOR** loops where first is for getting current and subdirectories and second for getting files from subdirectories.

```
set "source=C:\Program Files\WinRAR"

for /R /D %%s in (.\*) do (
    echo %%s
    for %%F in (%%s\*.txt*) do (
        "%source%\rar.exe" a -r -agYYYY-MM-DD -df -ep %%s\log_.rar %%F
    ) 
)
pause
```

Comment: So you took the code from my answer, made it more complex by adding a second __FOR__ loop which is absolutely not necessary and just increases the execution time of the batch file because *Rar* is started and terminated for each *.txt file separately instead of running once per directory, formatted the answer poorly, and had not even added a description. That's a poor performance and I suppose you are a friend of [darshan dave](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5286817/darshan-dave) as otherwise it is really not explainable for me why your answer was chosen for being accepted.

Comment: Then please you explain it how its possible without two for loops.. I was show your answer but can't get the output as per directory structure .. If I m not using two for loops then only one rar file is create which is not required

Comment: See my answer and try it out as I did. *Rar* supports not only a single file name to be specified on command line for compression into an archive, but multiple files and/or folders and/or a list file and as used in my answer a file pattern using a wildcard like `*.txt`. And since version 5.30 of *WinRAR* it is even possible to use wildcards in folder patterns as documented in `WhatsNew.txt` on point 5 of version 5.30. Please read text file `Rar.txt` for examples on using wildcards on compression or extraction.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your given information this should work.  If RAR.exe is not in a folder in your PATH variable you will need to add that path to the PATH variable or provide the full path to the executable in the batch file.

```
@echo off

:: Get Date
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%%a"
SET "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%"
SET "MM=%dt:~4,2%"
SET "DD=%dt:~6,2%"


FOR /D %%G IN (app*) DO (
    PUSHD "%%~G"
    rar a %DD%%MM%%YYYY%_log.rar *.txt
    del *.txt
    POPD
)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is the text file `Rar.txt` in program files folder of *WinRAR* which is the manual for console version `Rar.exe`. By viewing this file and first select the command to use – here it is `a` for *add files to archive* – and then reading from top to bottom about the switches and building the command line according to task requirements while reading makes it very easy to define the command line for compressing files into a RAR archive.

```
@echo off
for /D %%D in (app*) do (
    echo Creating archive for %%D ...
    "%ProgramFiles%\WinRAR\Rar.exe" a -agYYYY-MM-DD -cfg- -df -ep -idq -m5 -md4m -r- -s -y "%%D\log_.rar" "%%D\*.txt"
    if errorlevel 1 pause
)
```

You can read about all the switches in text file `Rar.txt`.

Command **PAUSE** is only executed if an error occurred output by `Rar.exe` to console while all other messages are suppressed because of switch `-idq`.

The file name format for the RAR archives is `log_YYYY-MM-DD.rar` because this is much better than `DD-MM-YYYY_log.rar` once you have multiple such RAR archives in a directory because `log_YYYY-MM-DD.rar` displayed sorted alphabetically according to file name as by default on Windows results in getting the files also automatically sorted by date with oldest at top.

*Rar* deletes only the text files successfully added to the archive.

It is of course also possible to use *WinRAR* for compression:

```
@echo off
for /D %%D in (app*) do (
    echo Creating archive for %%D ...
    "%ProgramFiles%\WinRAR\WinRar.exe" a -agYYYY-MM-DD -cfg- -df -ep -ibck -m5 -md4m -r- -s -y "%%D\log_.rar" "%%D\*.txt"
)
```

*WinRAR* could create also ZIP archives instead of RAR archives which console version *Rar* does not support.

*Rar* switch `-idq` is replaced by *WinRAR* switch `-ibck` to run *WinRAR* minimized to system tray, i.e. in background. Error messages are displayed in a GUI window which is displayed automatically by *WinRAR* if an error occurs.

For help on *WinRAR* commands and switches which slightly differ from *Rar* switches click in *WinRAR* in menu **Help** on **Help topics** and click on tab **Contents** on item **Command line mode** and read the linked pages.

For understanding the used Windows commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `for /?`

Look how easy it is to archive files using *Rar* or *WinRAR*. All really needed is a look into manual respectively help and little knowledge about standard commands of Windows listed on executing `help` in a command prompt window.

**EDIT:**

Both batch files above require that the batch file is in directory containing the subdirectories `app*` and this directory is the current directory. For executing this batch file for example as scheduled task with current directory being `%SystemRoot%\System32` the batch code below would be better:

```
@echo off
for /D %%D in ("%~dp0app*) do (
    echo Creating archive for %%~fD ...
    "%ProgramFiles%\WinRAR\Rar.exe" a -agYYYY-MM-DD -cfg- -df -ep -idq -m5 -md4m -r- -s -y "%%~fD\log_.rar" "%%~fD\*.txt"
    if errorlevel 1 pause
)
```

The command **FOR** searches for subdirectories `app*` now in directory of the batch file independent on what is the current directory. And passed to *Rar* is now name of archive file with full path and the file name pattern `*.txt` also with full path instead of using a path relative to current directory.

Well, the line `if errorlevel 1 pause` should be removed on using this batch file as scheduled task.